# Не работает SuperObject в Delphi 2010

Tags: delphi, json, delphi-2010

Подключил к проекту модуль [SuperObject](https://github.com/hgourvest/superobject) для разбора JSON.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Json: ISuperObject;
begin
  Json := SO(Memo1.Text);
end;
```

При компиляции вот такая ошибка:

> [DCC Error] Generics.Collections.pas(1679): E2250 There is no overloaded version of 'Create' that can be called with these arguments
>   [DCC Fatal Error] Generics.Defaults.pas(111): F2063 Could not compile used unit 'Generics.Collections'

Comment: Текст JSON-а валидный? Ошибка почему-то внутри дженериков, а не в вашем коде..

Comment: Валидный, но это не имеет значения, ведь до компиляции дело не доходит.

Comment: В штатном D2010 на строке 1679 никаким конструктором не пахнет, там реализация метода `function TDictionary<TKey, TValue>.TPairEnumerator.DoGetCurrent`. Попробуйте сделать Build проекту, скорее всего - Delphi покажет строку в самом модуле, который не может скомпилировать. Возможно, этот Generics.Collections не из штатной поставки.